# Communicating 2 application on wince device

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-ce

I have 2 applications running on a WinCE 6.0 device and both are written on Visual C#, I need to pass info between the 2 apps and do some actions inside, so I create 2 servers on each and 2 clients, on the application A the server is running on port 1287 and on application B on port 10001, the problem is that the client of application A is loosing the connection, but on the log of the server on application B is sending the correct response,  I keep getting an IOException and I can't find why, however when I am debugging, step by step the connection works fine and the apps work fine together, but if I left them run on their own I keep getting the error screens I create for this cases, this is the message I got on application A:

```
DEBUG || TcpWrapperServer || Socket closed...
DEBUG || TcpClient || Enviando solicitud(110.152.100.117:10001):{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|0002149}
DEBUG || TcpClient || try/catch
DEBUG || TcpClient || Connecting... 110.152.100.117:10001
DEBUG || TcpClient || getStream()...
DEBUG || TcpClient || preparing to read stream...
DEBUG || TcpClient ||
WARNING data not available...
ERROR || TcpClient || IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection.
ERROR || TcpClient || IOException(InnerExc): System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveNoCheck(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 request, SocketFlags socketFlags)
ERROR || TcpClient || IOException(traace): at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer) at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
at pvc_20.pvcTcpClient.sendRequest(String msg) at pvc_20.BarcodeSession.proccessPartnerID(String partnerid)
```

this is the log on server on app B:

```
INFO || TcpServerWrapper ||  ProcessClient ||
DEBUG ||TcpWrapperServer || processCommand ||  msg:{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|0001371}   
DEBUG || TcpWrapperServer || processCommand || response:{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|ONPROCESS}
```

also this is the log that I get when I debug:

```
DEBUG || TcpClient || Enviando
solicitud(110.152.100.117:10001):{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|0001371}
DEBUG || TcpClient || try/catch 1/1/2000  
DEBUG || TcpClient || Connecting...110.152.100.117:10001   
DEBUG || TcpClient || getStream()...   
DEBUG || TcpClient || reading stream...   
DEBUG || TcpClient || respuesta recibida:{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|ONPROCESS}
```

this is the client part on application A:

```
public TcpClient() {
            m_server = Settings.ServerIP;
            m_tcpPort = Settings.TcpPort;
            m_hasReponse = false;
            m_response = String.Empty;
            m_buffer = null;
        }

        public TcpClient( String server , int tcpPort)
        {
            m_server = server;
            m_tcpPort = tcpPort;
            m_hasReponse = false;
            m_response = String.Empty;
            m_buffer = null;
        }

       public void sendRequest(String msg)
        {
           Log.debug("TcpClient", "sending to (" + m_server + ":" + m_tcpPort+"):"+ msg);
           string m_currentIP = Utils.LocalIPAddress();
           m_clientSocket = null;
           m_hasReponse = false;
           m_response = String.Empty;
           Log.debug("TcpClient", "try/catch");
            try
            {
                m_clientSocket = new TcpClient();
                Log.debug("TcpClient", "Connecting... "+m_server+":"+ m_tcpPort);
                m_clientSocket.Connect(
                    new IPEndPoint(
                        IPAddress.Parse(m_server), 
                        m_tcpPort)  );
                Log.debug("TcpClient", "getStream()...");
                m_stream = m_clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] outstream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                m_stream.Write(outstream, 0, outstream.Length);
                m_stream.Flush();


                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(m_stream);


                if (m_stream.CanRead)
                {
                    Log.debug("TcpClient", "preparing to read stream...");
                    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
                    byte[] inStream = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesread = 0;
                    int index = 0;
                    char[] bfrRes = new char[1024];

                    if (!m_stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        Log.debug("TcpClient", "warning data not available...");

                    }


                   /* while (bytesread != 125)
                    {

                        bytesread = m_stream.ReadByte();
                        Log.debug("TcpClient", "reading byte: " + bytesread);
                        char c;
                        try
                        {
                            c = Convert.ToChar(bytesread);                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            c = ' ';
                        }
                        res.Append(c);
                        index++;
                    }*/


                        streamReader.Read(bfrRes, 0, 1024);  


                   // m_response = res.ToString();
                    m_response = new string(bfrRes);
                    Log.debug("TcpClient", "response:" + m_response);
                }

                if (m_response.Length > 0)
                    m_hasReponse = true;
                else
                    m_hasReponse = false;
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Log.error("TcpClient", "SocketException: "+e.Message);
                m_hasReponse= false;
                m_response = String.Empty;
            }catch(WebException we){
                Log.error("TcpClient", "Webxception: " + we.Message);
                Log.error("TcpClient", "WebException(InnerExc): " + we.InnerException);
                Log.error("TcpClient", "WebException(traace): " + we.StackTrace);
                m_hasReponse = false;
                m_response = String.Empty;
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {

                Log.error("TcpClient", "IOException: " + ioe.Message);
                Log.error("TcpClient", "IOException(InnerExc): " + ioe.InnerException);
                Log.error("TcpClient", "IOException(trace): " + ioe.StackTrace);
                m_hasReponse = false;
                m_response = String.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.error("TcpClient","Exception:"+ e.Message);
                m_hasReponse = false;
                m_response = String.Empty;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != m_stream)
                    m_stream.Close();
                m_clientSocket.Close();
            }
            return ;
        }





       public String response
       {
           get { return m_response; }
       }


       public bool hasResponse {
           get { return m_hasReponse; }
       }

       public byte[] buffer {
           get { return m_buffer; }
       }
```

this is the server wraper side on application B:

```
class TcpServerWrapper
    {
        TcpClient m_client;
        WebClock m_main;

        bool isValidCommand = false;

        public TcpServerWrapper(TcpClient client, WebClock m)
        {
            Log.debug("TcpServerWrapper", "init");
            m_client = client;
            m_main = m;
        }

        public void ProcessClient()
        {
            String remoteIP = ((IPEndPoint)m_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            Log.info("TcpServerWrapper", " ProcessClient || Processing from:" + remoteIP);
            NetworkStream clientStream = m_client.GetStream();
            byte[] message = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead;
            bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                int i = 0;
                int b = 0;
                while (b != 125)
                {
                    b = clientStream.ReadByte();
                    message[i] = (byte)b;
                    i++;
                }
                bytesRead = message.Length;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                Log.error("TcpWrapperServer", "ProcessClient || Can't read client petition || ex:" + e.Message);
                bytesRead = 0;
                //break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                Log.warning("TcpWrapperServer", "ProcessClient || Client disconected ");
                //break;
            }
            else
            {

                //message has successfully been received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                String req = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                String res = processCommand(req);
                NetworkStream stream = m_client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(res);
                clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                clientStream.Flush();
            }

            clientStream.Close();
            m_client.Close();

            if (isValidCommand)
            {
                m_main.wakeApp("");
            }
            Log.debug("TcpWrapperServer", "ProcessClient ||  Socket closed");
        }


        private String processCommand(String msg)
        {
            Log.debug("TcpWrapperServer", "processCommand ||  msg:" + msg);
            String response = "";
            msg = msg.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
            msg = msg.ToUpper();
            if (!msg.StartsWith("{") || !msg.EndsWith("}"))
            {
                return "{WEBCLOCK| RESULT=ERROR|MESSAGE=El mensaje no es un comando valido de la aplicacion.}";
            }
            msg = msg.Replace("{", "");
            msg = msg.Replace("}", "");

            String[] commands = msg.Split('|');
            //{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|0001371}
            if (commands[0] == "WEBCLOCK")
            {

                if (commands[1] == "SHIFT")
                {

                    string socioid = commands[2];

                    if (socioid.Length == 7)
                    {
                        Settings.TMP_ScannedPartnerId = socioid;
                        isValidCommand = true;
                        response = "{WEBCLOCK|SHIFT|ONPROCESS}\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = "{WEBCLOCK| RESULT=ERROR|MESSAGE=El mensaje no es un comando valido de la aplicacion.}";
                    }


                }
                else {
                    response = "{WEBCLOCK| RESULT=ERROR|MESSAGE=El mensaje no es un comando valido de la aplicacion.}";
                }

            }else
            {
                response = "{WEBCLOCK| RESULT=ERROR|MESSAGE=El mensaje no es un comando valido para WEBCLOCK}";
            }

            Log.debug("TcpWrapperServer", "processCommand ||  response:" + response);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I really don't see why the local server on Application B is being closed.

Comment: Not that this shouldn't work, but Windows CE has a [Message Queue API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450574.aspx) that is useful for communicating between applications. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out, I didnt find this when I did my research, the only thing I found was this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446520.aspx  but was for CE 1.0 I supposed there should be something better by the CE 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified you're not hitting the [ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx)?

Comment: yes I check it, the conecction get cut down when the response is being reading, I was thinking that maybe it is a character at the beggining of the response, but I didnt find something out of place.